# Add <!DOCTYPE to serialized xml from symfony serializer

Tags: php, serialization, xmlserializer, symfony-serializer

There is [xmlencoder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#the-xmlencoder) in symfony [serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), by using that we achive this.

```
$data = ['foo' => 'Foo value'];
$encoder = new XmlEncoder();
$encoder->encode($data, 'xml');

// is encoded as follows:
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <response>
//     <foo>
//        Foo value
//     </foo>
// </response>
```

Now we need to add **<!DOCTYPE** something like below

```
// is encoded as follows:
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <!DOCTYPE response SYSTEM "pathto.dtd">
// <response>
// .....
```

Is there a way to achieve this with symfony serializer?